# tc filter does not match ip address, only range

Tags: linux, trafficshaping

I am trying to build virtual network for simulation. Links are determined by IP addresses and I can shape traffic and set up delay for range defined by netmask

```
#!/bin/bash
VETH_1="vethf4dbb89"

tc qdisc del dev $VETH_1 root

tc qdisc add dev $VETH_1 root handle 1: htb default 14
tc class add dev $VETH_1 parent 1: classid 1:0 htb rate 1000Mbps

tc class add dev $VETH_1 parent 1:0 classid 1:2 htb rate 1000Mbps
tc class add dev $VETH_1 parent 1:0 classid 1:3 htb rate 1000Mbps
tc class add dev $VETH_1 parent 1:0 classid 1:4 htb rate 1000Mbps
tc class add dev $VETH_1 parent 1:0 classid 1:5 htb rate 1000Mbps


tc qdisc add dev $VETH_1 parent 1:2 handle 12: netem loss 0% 1% delay 30ms 10ms
tc qdisc add dev $VETH_1 parent 1:3 handle 13: netem loss 0% 1% delay 200ms 10ms
tc qdisc add dev $VETH_1 parent 1:4 handle 14: netem loss 0% 1% delay 10ms 10ms
tc qdisc add dev $VETH_1 parent 1:5 handle 15: netem loss 0% 1% delay 15ms 10ms

tc filter add dev $VETH_1 parent 1: protocol ip prio 1 u32 match ip dst 172.17.0.3/24 flowid 1:2
```

But I need filter only specific IP address like

```
tc filter add dev $VETH_1 parent 1: protocol ip prio 1 u32 match ip dst 172.17.0.3 flowid 1:2 
tc filter add dev $VETH_1 parent 1: protocol ip prio 1 u32 match ip dst 172.17.0.4 flowid 1:3 
tc filter add dev $VETH_1 parent 1: protocol ip prio 1 u32 match ip dst 172.17.0.5 flowid 1:4 
tc filter add dev $VETH_1 parent 1: protocol ip prio 1 u32 match ip dst 172.17.0.6 flowid 1:5
```

In first case with /24 all packets are captured correctly. Second configuration without netmask does not capture any packet.

```
tc -s qdisc ls dev veth09840d5
qdisc htb 1: root refcnt 2 r2q 10 default 14 direct_packets_stat 110795 direct_qlen 2
 Sent 268440356 bytes 269182 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0) 
 backlog 0b 0p requeues 0 
qdisc netem 12: parent 1:2 limit 1000 delay 30.0ms  10.0ms
 Sent 0 bytes 0 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0) 
 backlog 0b 0p requeues 0 
qdisc netem 13: parent 1:3 limit 1000 delay 200.0ms  10.0ms
 Sent 0 bytes 0 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0) 
 backlog 0b 0p requeues 0 
qdisc netem 14: parent 1:4 limit 1000 delay 10.0ms  10.0ms
 Sent 0 bytes 0 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0) 
 backlog 0b 0p requeues 0 
qdisc netem 15: parent 1:5 limit 1000 delay 15.0ms  10.0ms
 Sent 0 bytes 0 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0) 
 backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
```

EDIT:
Only ip address that is assigned to defined interface is captured as destination. But how to slow down other ip addresses?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use iptables to mark packets and check whether it catch your traffic from certain ip.

Comment: Could you expand on your comments or give links to resources explaining how to do what you are describing?